# Is the set of non-deterministic Turing machines countable?

Tags: turing-machines, enumeration

We know that deterministic TMs are countable (enumeration). Does the same hold for NTMs? Are TMs and NTMS equinumerous?

Comment: What are the differences between the representation of a TM and a representation of a NTM? Can these differences make an enumeration of the NTMs uncountable?

Comment: How do we know that deterministic TMs are countable? Can that technique be used for nondeterministic TMs, too?

Comment: Is there a syntax that you can use to describe NTMs?

Comment: Due to popular demand, I deleted my hint, which was: a non-deterministic Turing machine can be described by a string, and so...

Comment: if every element of a set is fully communicable to someonelse (i.e. you can describe it without ambiguity), then the set of these elements is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the class of DTM countable? Because you can code every DTM as a string (the program) over some alphabet. Now you can sort these strings lexicographicaly. Then the function 
$$f(i\in \mathbb{N}):=\text{the $i$th string in the sorted sequence of DTMs},$$
is a bijection between the natural numbers and the set of DTMs. Hence the set of DTMs is countable.

Now here is the point. You can argue the same for NTMs. Hence the set of DTMs and NTMs are both countable and therefore equinumerous.